# Params unknown (Play! Framework)

Tags: java, forms, playframework, parameters, playframework-1.x

It's a bit early on a Sunday morning for this (sorry) but here goes.

The form I am working on is has a list of users (checkboxes) and some other fields below (dates, etc). The purpose of the form is to bulk add objects. So, for each of these checkboxes (users) add an object with the user and the dates.

The problem that I have is that I don't know how to capture the id's passed back through from params as I don't know the params names being passed through. Can you help?

Comment: We don't names of these parami as well. We even don't which version Play are you using, or what did you try.

Comment: I can prefix the param name with something but I can't work out how to get that out in the controller. Currently, the HTML fields are named "user.${u.id}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use u_index if you are in a list tag to have an index for your users

In you view

```
#{list users, as:'u'}
  <input type="hidden" name="users[$[u_index -1].id" value="${u.id}">
#{/list}
```

and in your controller

```
public static void save(List<User> users) {
}
```